# Json change key to value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm looking for a way in javascript to transform this json to something else.

```
{ 
  "John Doe": {
     "place": "Amsterdam"
  },
  "Jane Doe": {
     "place": "Paris"
  }
}
```

To something like this:

```
{ 
  { "id": 0,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "place": "Amsterdam"
  },
  { "id": 1,
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "place": "Paris"
  },
}
```

How can I achieve this with javascript?

Comment: For starters, even after correcting the mismatched quotes the target format isn't a valid JavaScript object.  Aside from that... What have you tried and what didn't work?  Are you just asking how to loop over the keys in an object?

Comment: Please just learn to use JSON properly, then come up with an idea (even a prototype is enough). What's the point in publishing a question like this?

Comment: Sorry mate, I'm just starting this is my first question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` to get `key/value` pair and use `map` method to transform the object into the new one.

```js
const data = { 
  "John Doe": {
     "place": "Amsterdam"
  },
  "Jane Doe": {
     "place": "Paris"
  }
}


const result = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value], index) => ({
  id: index,
  name: key,
  place: value.place
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for! Can't vote your answer yet. Just starting..

Answer (score 1):

You can map the entries to objects. You can mix destructuring and object property shorthand to simplify this greatly.

**Note:** Order is not guaranteed when iterating through an object's keys.

```js
const obj = { 
  "John Doe": { "place": "Amsterdam" },
  "Jane Doe": { "place": "Paris" },
};

const list = Object.entries(obj)
  .map(([name, { place }], id) =>
    ({ id, name, place }));

console.log(list);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```